# How to avoid installing an "install_requires" package of a pip requirement?

Tags: pip, setuptools, distutils

When installing with pip from a requirements.txt file, is there a way to override a requirement's dependencies which are installed due to being listed under `install_requires` in setup.py of the package?

My specific case is `south` being installed as a dependency of `django-paypal`, even though I'm using Django 1.8 so I don't want `south` installed - it just confuses django's own `migrate` command.

Comment: I doubt you can do this with pip. However, what about removing `south` later? `pip uninstall south`?

Comment: This could get a bit ugly e.g. when deploying to heroku, all requirements are automatically installed, included the undesired one. It would be nice to be able to override it.

Comment: add removal of undesired package(s) to your deployment script. `install_requires` is a list of packages which are minimally **required** to be present so a project can work. If `django-paypal` works without `south` then `south` should be listed as `extras`. Try to contact project's maintainer and ask him to move the dependency. It would be the best solution.

Comment: south is actually an *optional* requirement of django-paypal, depending on what django version is used. I'd rather override install_requires if it is somehow possible. It seems cleaner to me then adding an uninstall to the deployment script.